# Sql query for records which has entry but not exit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a travellers table

```
travellers(id,full_name)
```

and another table of traveller_history

```
travellers_history(id,traveller_id,status)
```

The status in travellers_history is a number field

I want record of all the travellers which has record of status 11 in traveller_history records but doesn't have record of status 12 in traveller_history.How do I achieve this in sql ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired rsults.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the travellers that have more "11"s than "12":

```
select th.traveller_id
from traveller_history th
group by th.traveller_id
having sum( status = 11 ) > sum( status = 12 )
```

Comment: What if I want full_name also from travellers

Comment: Then you would join in the `travellers` table and include the name in the `select` and `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables, group by traveler and set the conditions in the having clause:

```
select t.id, t.full_name 
from travellers t inner join travellers_history h
on h.traveller_id = t.id
group by t.id, t.full_name
having sum(h.status = 12) = 0 and sum(h.status = 11) > 0
```

or:

```
select t.id, t.full_name 
from travellers t inner join travellers_history h
on h.traveller_id = t.id
where h.status in (11, 12)
group by t.id, t.full_name
having max(h.status) = 11
```